# Cannot properly run MSTest with arguments in Powershell

Tags: .net, powershell, mstest

I am trying to run `MSTest` in Powershell. One of the options to pass is `/testcontainer` and it can be passed multiple times.

In my script I need to build the option string as I can have many test containers passed to the script, thus this is what I do:

```
param(
  [string[]] $TestContainers = @(
    'C:\Users\myuser\MyProject\test\Test1\bin\Debug\Test1.dll', 
    'C:\Users\myuser\MyProject\test\Test1\bin\Debug\Test2.dll', 
    'C:\Users\myuser\MyProject\test\Test1\bin\Debug\Test3.dll', 
    'C:\Users\myuser\MyProject\test\Test1\bin\Debug\Test4.dll'
  )
);

$TestContainersOptions = @();
foreach ($TestContainer in $TestContainers)
{
  $TestContainersOptions += "/testcontainer:'$TestContainer'";
}

$MSTestPath = "C:\Program...\MsTest.exe"

& $MSTestPath $TestContainersOptions;
```

When I run the script I get:

> Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 14.0.23107.0
>   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> The given path's format is not supported. For switch syntax, type
>   "MSTest /help"

What to do?

Comment: Your second argument to `&` should be a string array as well: `$TestContainersOptions = $TestContainers|%{"/testcontainer:'$_'"}; & $MSTestPath $TestContainersOptions`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: I thins your comment is worth an answer... I will try that!

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: Well it gets better, but I get: The given path's format is not supported. But if I run the command manually it works!

Comment: I'd imagine it having a problem with `'` vs. `"`. You can escape `"` inside a double-quoted string by entering in twice: `"/testcontainer:""$TestContainer"""`

Comment: Oh yes! That was it! Man thanks, please post it as an answer, I'll mark it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose each path in `"` (escape sequence for double-quotes is just two in a row, `""`):

```
$TestContainersOptions = foreach ($TestContainer in $TestContainers)
{
    "/testcontainer:""$TestContainer"""
}
```

If you assign the output from the `foreach` loop directly to the variable (as shown above), you don't have to declare it as an array beforehand